# Oracle 12 Unique constraint for row combination

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I have 3 columns: `A, B, C`. 
`A` is pkid, `B` and `C` are Varchars. I already wrote such a constraint: 
`CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_DATA1 UNIQUE(B, C)`. This prevents the insertion of the values "x" and "y" twice, but i would also like to prevent the insertion of "y" and "x" if the "x" and "y" values already exist. 
Is there a way to put this constraint in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function-based index:

```
create unique index unique_data2 (least(b,c), greatest(b,c));
```

That will only work if both values can never be null.  If they can you could do something like:

```
create unique index unique_data2 
  ( least(nvl(b,'~),nvl(c,'~'))
  , greatest(nvl(b,'~),nvl(c,'~'))
  );
```

where '~' is a string you know will never be a real value of b or c.

Comment: They can never be null, works like a charm! Thank you!